# Why is my SQL query slower when I specify ROWNUM, than when I specify date range in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-performance

I'm trying to achieve pagination of a large dataset. I figured this might work

```sql
select asortyment.nazwa as NAZWA,
  parpoz.ilosc as ILOSC,
  parpoz.cenabrutto as CENA,
  parnagl.data as DATA
from parnagl

inner join ParPoz on ParPoz.ParNaglID=ParNagl.ParNaglID 
inner join asortyment on asortyment.poztowid=parpoz.poztowid 
inner join grupapt on asortyment.grupaptid=grupapt.grupaptid
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```

This takes 12 seconds to perform.
On the other hand, if I specify date range using WHERE clause, it only takes 50ms... Is there any way I could optimise this?

The database is Oracle 11g.

Comment: can you post the explain plan for the query?

Comment: Can you use both?

Comment: Look at explain plan...id expect rownum is done AFTER all data is accumulated...whereas the date filter is reducing data prejoin

Comment: @Mech I feel like doing date range is suboptimal, it'll yield inconsistent chunk sizes... I'd rather have some form of proper pagination here.

Comment: @OldProgrammer thanks for replying. I actually tried running this one,  problem is I have no admin access to the DB... I was granted a permission to do some read-only stuff on the DB view, and that's it.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 thank you so much it makes sense actually. How would I achieve some form of consitent pagination then? use PK instead of ROWNUM?

Comment: Doesn't it only make sense to use a rownum if you're also doing a sort?

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm leaving sorting for later, for now I'll be happy with any sort of working interface. I don't consider 12 seconds per-response working :)

Comment: In comments you talk about pagination, and all sorts of other issues. Why is there no mention of them in the post itself? In the post you are just asking why one query is faster than the other - you are not stating a problem you need help on.

Comment: That's a good point, what I'm trying to achieve is in fact pagination...

Answer (score 2):

There's too little information to answer the question. Without the schema, it's hard to guess what the QO might be doing. Without the schema, we still might make progress if we had the execution plan. But the execution plan isn't given, either.

We have to remember that without a limiting `WHERE` clause, the correct execution of the query mandates that the database might need to exhaustively try to produce all available rows. Then, it will produce only the first 10 ... whatever those might be since there's no ordering given.

But with a limiting `WHERE` clause, the query plan might not demand such a wide-open execution plan to be correct. In fact, it can first limit itself to finding rows that match the date range in the first place. Depending on the index structure, filtering the dates first might be immensely faster.

What if 2 billion rows satisfy the unlimited `JOIN` without a date specified?

And what if just 2 rows match only the date range specified, and then only one of those two fits through the `JOIN`  criteria?

Which of the two queries do you think would execute faster?

So I guess the next piece of information missing is apparent: What do you want the query to do? Using a `ROWNUM` limit without an ordering is pretty weird, but maybe you have an interesting case where it is useful. OTOH, if using the date range is faster ... why not use the date range?

Comment: tbh I just wanted to achieve pagination, seems like date ranges is the way to go then...